# How to configure JPA sql logs into spring-boot-starter-log4j2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, logging, log4j2

Problem statement:

I have implemented log4j2 in spring boot project (1.4.0.RELEASE).

Now I want to add Hibernate SQL queries logs into log4j2 logging file.

I am not able to add sql queries generated by hibernate into log4j2 logging.

Please suggest.

Versions used are:
log4j2 dependency used: `compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'`

JPA version used: `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.4.0.RELEASE")`

Comment: Could you please post the content of the `pom.xml` and the content of the logging configuration file?

Comment: Hi @SergeyBrunov